# How to cleanup after deleting a Realm Object in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I would like to store files with Realm. My intention is to store the file on disk and save the name of the file in a Realm Object. When the object is deleted for any reason I would also like to delete the file associated with that object.

How do I delete the associated data from disk when the realm object is deleted?

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way to accomplish this , you need to have a unique id for the object ( preferred if it's a primary key ) , and when you execute `realm.delete(obj)` , `removeItem` from where it's in disk ( documents or any other place  )